# Handlebars + passport js

Tags: handlebars.js

I'm using handlebars as a view engine.

For routes :

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    if(req.user) {res.render('user'), {name:req.user.username, id:req.user.id}}

    else

    if(!req.user) {res.render('index')};

});
```

For passport.js

```
 passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});


passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ? ",[id], function(err, rows){
        done(err, rows[0]);
    });
});


passport.use(
    'local-signup',
    new LocalStrategy({

            usernameField : 'username',
            passwordField : 'password',
            passReqToCallback : true 
        },
        function(req, username, password, done) {
            // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
            // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
            connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?",[username], function(err, rows) {
                if (err)
                    return done(err);
                if (rows.length) {
                    return done(null, false, {message: 'That username is already taken'});

                    } else {

                    var newUserMysql = {
                        username: username,
                        password: bcrypt.hashSync(password, null, null)  // use the generateHash function in our user model
                    };

                    var insertQuery = "INSERT INTO users ( username, password ) values (?,?)";

                    connection.query(insertQuery,[newUserMysql.username, newUserMysql.password],function(err, rows) {
                        newUserMysql.id = rows.insertId;

                        return done(null, newUserMysql);
                    });
                }
            });
        })
);
```

I'm trying to find a solution, but it doesn't work. Whenever I try to use this, handlebars won't show anything up.. I know that ejs uses something like <%= user.username %> that does work, but can't convert that to handlebars..

Answer (score 0):

```
if(req.user) {res.render('user'), {name:req.user.username, id:req.user.id}}
```

I figured it out till the end, my object {} was outside the (), not inside like it was supposed to be. This is the right code:

```
if(req.user) {res.render('user', {name:req.user.username, id:req.user.id})}
```